# how to make two 3 columns are unique in SQL server ?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to make three columns are unique in my data table

```
-----------------------------------
 Column A  |  Column B | Column C
----------------------------------
  Kasun     Cham      Nimith   
----------------------------------
  Kasun     Cham      Rox      - This row ok and must be allowed to add.
----------------------------------
  Kasun     Cham      Nimith  -  but This row must not be allowed to add again, 
---------------------------------
```

how can I accomplish this in SQL server ?

Comment: make Columns A,B,C primary keys?

Comment: @Reyno that will cause every PK column to have a unique entry per row. Wont work with the above case.

Comment: @Chris'o - It will work fine. `CREATE TABLE X(A VARCHAR(10), B VARCHAR(10), C VARCHAR(10), PRIMARY KEY(A,B,C))` ensures that the **combination** of `a,b,c` is unique.

Comment: Refer to composite primary key http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922337/how-to-create-composite-primary-key-in-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code will do that what you want.

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX index_name ON TABLE (col1,col2, col3)
or
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX index_name ON TABLE (col1,col2 , col3)

or

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TABLE] ADD CONSTRAINT
UNIQUE_Table UNIQUE CLUSTERED
(
col1,
col2, 
col3
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 8):

You can add a unique constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE [TableName] ADD CONSTRAINT  [constraintName] UNIQUE ([columns])
```

You can read the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186712.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

To handle that issue with this table design, you need to create a unique constraint on your columns A/B/C.