# Creating a table with duplicate primary keys

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I create a Table in SQL Server that has a `Primary Key` and a `Foreign Key`, but the Primary Key data should be repeated?

For example:

```
PK   FK
1    100
2    100
1    200
3    100
4    200
4    100
4    300
```

Comment: Edit your question. Don't use caps-lock. Move question from title to body etc.

Comment: You can't. As Jaco said, *by definition*, a primary key is unique.

Comment: The primary key cannot be repeated. Create another primary key (id) column.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is unanswerable.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling The question is certainly answerable.  The answer is "You can't."

Comment: Just create a composite primary key, check here http://stackoverflow.com/a/3922359/3470178

Answer (score 4):

A primary key is unique by definition, you can't have repeated values for your primary key column(s).

Comment: Almost correct. A column in a composite pk can have repeated values...

Comment: @bhanuprakash STOP SHOUTING AT US.  If you want to insert data like that, either don't constrain it, or make it a compound key.

Comment: Or add another column and use THAT as the PK.

Comment: please help me out..i have to implement it in my project

Comment: ok thank you i will try..