# How to make a identity column for a 2-key primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my fictional tables:

```
Post{
    Post-Id int primary key identity,
    Post-another-columns blahblahblah
}

Lamp{
    Lamp-Id int primary key identity,
    Lamp-another-columns blahblahblah
}

Post-Lamp(n-n Relationship){
    Post-Id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Posts(Post-Id), 
    Lamp-Id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Lamp(Lamp-Id), 
    Lamp-Index int not null, --(describe the Lamp index that is in this Post)
    Post-Bar-another-columns blahblahblah,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Post_Lamp PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([Post-Id], [Lamp-Id])
}
```

On my .Net code, every time that i put a Lamp into a Post, i insert a index based at the **MAX** index that a Post has of the Lamps. It's a `foreach Lamp in Post, insert into Post-Lamp(postId, index, lampId)`, but this seems very wrong.
How can i make a incremental column for the Lamp-Index that respects each change of Post-Id?

Edit: .Net code

```
int postId = await _repositories.Post.Add(post);

List<LampPost> lamps = model.Lamp.Select((l, i) => new { Lamp = l, Index = i })
                .Select(item => new LampPost
                {
                    LampId= item.Lamp,
                    LampIndex = item.Index,
                    PostId = postId,
                }).ToList();

            await _repositories.Lamp.Add(lamps);
```

Comment: If I understand what you are doing, you should insert a Post and a Lamp then use the id's generated in those tables to insert a Post-Lamp.

Comment: Every time that i add a Post-Lamp relation, i already add the lamp and the post id on a new row, but i need to add incremental column for arch Lamp in a post

Comment: To us (me), Lamp is not IN Post or vice versa but both are in Post-Lamp as the linking table.  Thus your comment is a bit confusing that you try to insert Lamp in Post.  You would insert Lamp in Post-Lamp right?

Comment: You lost me. I don't understand.

Comment: "On my .Net code," perhaps show that so we gain insight into what you are trying to do.

Comment: Does that index have to restart with 1 (or 0) for every post? Or is the actual value not important but the possibility to determine which lamp was added after which in a post?

Comment: They have to restart for every post. If not possible, i will just make a simple identity column and then count a select for an specific post

Comment: @WillianSoares: Sounds like a feasible approach. You could also look into a solution using triggers, but as SQL Server has no row level triggers, that might also need and identity column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, maybe you can easily solve this by using a view.

First create the linking table with and identity column, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE postlamp_t
             (post integer,
              lamp integer,
              lampindex integer IDENTITY,
              PRIMARY KEY (post
                           lamp),
              FOREIGN KEY (post)
                          REFERENCES post
                                     (id),
              FOREIGN KEY (lamp)
                          REFERENCES lamp
                                     (id));
```

Now create a view using the `row_number()` window function to calculate the index per post.

```
CREATE VIEW postlamp
AS
SELECT post,
       lamp,
       row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY post
                          ORDER BY lampindex) lampindex
       FROM postlamp_t;
```

As long as you don't try to update the calculated column, this view is updatable and you can use it like if it was the actual linking table (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `SELECT`).

Find a demonstration at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=a4f5512f667e862e1f4c79d84d07b6ca).

(Side note: If a lamp shouldn't be in two different posts at a time, which seems realistic if we're talking actual real world lamps, consider a unique constraint on the lamp in the linking table.)

Comment: This is what i want! Actually, the lamp table references a type of a lamp and the instance of a lamp inside a post only exists at the postlamp relation, but this view works fine and i will adapt on my project.

Answer (score 1):

Your question title makes it sound like you want a [composite primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922337/how-to-create-composite-primary-key-in-sql-server-2008), but I think what you are trying to achieve by your example is just a table with 2 foreign keys like this:

```
create table Posts(
  PostId int, 
  OtherColumn varchar(50), 
  primary key (PostId)
)

create table Lamps(
  LampId int, 
  OtherColumn varchar(50), 
  primary key (LampId)
)

create table PostLamp(
  PostId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Posts(PostId), 
  LampId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Lamps(LampId), 
)
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to say that i already have foreign keys referencing each table

Comment: Table `PostLamp` should still have it's own primary key, which should probably be `PostId, LampId`.

Answer (score 0):

Whats the difference between
Lamp-Id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Lamp(Lamp-Id) and Lamp-Index int not null ??

I'm little confused with the title, but seems like you should check out SCOPE_IDENTITY(). It returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope. In your stored proc that inserts values in Lamp table set a variable with Scope_Identity() after inserting a lamp  and then us that variable in Lamp-Post insert query..

Comment: I can't have a Entity Framework beacuse the DB is huge and it's already done. I'm just making a update.