# How to create key (Primary Key) below table in Sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints, primary-key

[image: Table details(image)]

Given 2 column X and Y. 
How to create a primary key on the table?

Comment: Hi Viv, Microsoft has some good documentation on that subject you should give a gander: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-primary-keys?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Looking at your data, I'm sure it's just test data, but creating a composite primary key would fail because of the `1 / B` combination, there are 2 rows with the duplicate data.

Comment: (Obviously) This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. In code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code & desired output & clear specification & explanation. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) PS This is unclear. What PK?

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

```
CREATE TABLE SAMPLE_TABLE
(X integer,
Y varchar(1),
PRIMARY KEY (X, Y));
```

The term you are looking for is *composite* or *compound key*. I got this answer by referencing [this link](https://www.1keydata.com/blog/composite-key-in-sql.html) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922337/how-to-create-composite-primary-key-in-sql-server-2008), so please research other posts before asking here.

Comment: This is obviously a duplicate so should be closed & not answered. See [ask], [answer] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Neither the question nor this answer are 'useful'.

Comment: Noted. Thanks seinfeld

Comment: I don't understand the 2nd sentence of your comment. If it's negative, that is not welcome here.

Comment: Nope, my bad. My colleague's name is seinfeld. Thanks phil. I'll note it for next time. The links and the explanation are helpful, but your attitude is not. I ask that you [Be Nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) lol.

Comment: I do not have a bad attitude & I have no idea what you think my attitude is or why. I stated some helpful things. It would be helpful if you just wrote clearly instead of cryptically.